# Cant access memory location declared in array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my code ;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *D = new int[20000];
    D = { 0 };
    cout << D[0];    
}
```

At the `cout` statement I get an access violation error irrespective of the size of the array.
Why ?

Comment: 'D = { 0 }' - now your pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: Have you looked at your debugger output?

Comment: Semi-OT: I suggest you to use std::vector instead, you will avoid this and a lot more problems.

Comment: For future reference [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) should be of use

Comment: One C++ surprise (inherited from C) is that your `D = { 0 };` is equivalent to `D = 0;`.

Answer (score 5):

Because

```
D = {0};
```

sets the pointer `D` to the value `0`, i.e. `nullptr`. Trying then to de-reference

```
cout << D[0];
```

a null pointer is UB (undefined behaviour).

In case you wanted to set the **first** element of the array to zero, you need to do

```
D[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You set D to zero, so D points to NULL, which is an invalid memory address. Maybe you wanted to write:

```
*D = { 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that from C++11, braced-init-list could be used as the operand of the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment).

> For expressions `E1` of any scalar type `T`, the following additional
>   forms of the builtin assignment expression are allowed:
>
> ```
> E1 = {}   (since C++11)
> E1 = {E2} (since C++11)
> ```
>
> If the right operand is a braced-init-list
>
> if the expression `E1` has scalar type,
>
> - the expression `E1 = {}` is equivalent to `E1 = T{}`, where `T` is the type of `E1`.
> - the expression `E1 = {E2}` is equivalent to `E1 = T{E2}`, where `T` is the type of `E1`.

That means `D = { 0 };` is equivalent with `D = int* {0};`, which means assign the null pointer to `D`. Then any dereference on `D` would be undefined behavior.

You can't assign the whole array via `D = {0};`. If your intent is to make all the elements' value to `0`, you can do that at its initialization. e.g.

```
int *D = new int[20000]{0}; // initialize all the elements to 0
int *D = new int[20000]{};  // same as above
```